# Implementing an enrichment using Spark with MySQL is bad idea?

Tags: mysql, database, apache-spark

I am trying to build one giant schema that makes data users to query easier, in order to achieve that, streaming events have to be joined with `User Metadata` by `USER_ID and ID`. In data engineering, This operation is called "Data Enrichment" right? the tables below are the example.

```
# `Event` (Stream)

+---------+--------------+---------------------+
| UERR_ID |    EVENT     |      TIMESTAMP      |
+---------+--------------+---------------------+
|       1 | page_view    | 2020-04-10T12:00:11 |
|       2 | button_click | 2020-04-10T12:01:23 |
|       3 | page_view    | 2020-04-10T12:01:44 |
+---------+--------------+---------------------+


# `User Metadata` (Static)

+----+-------+--------+
| ID | NAME  | GENDER |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | Matt  | MALE   |
|  2 | John  | MALE   |
|  3 | Alice | FEMALE |
+----+-------+--------+



==> # Result

+---------+--------------+---------------------+-------+--------+
| UERR_ID |    EVENT     |      TIMESTAMP      | NAME  | GENDER |
+---------+--------------+---------------------+-------+--------+
|       1 | page_view    | 2020-04-10T12:00:11 | Matt  | MALE   |
|       2 | button_click | 2020-04-10T12:01:23 | John  | MALE   |
|       3 | page_view    | 2020-04-10T12:01:44 | Alice | FEMALE |
+---------+--------------+---------------------+-------+--------+
```

I was developing this using Spark, and `User Metadata` is stored in MySQL, then I realized it would be waste of parallelism of Spark if the spark code includes joining with MySQL tables right?

The bottleneck will be happening on MySQL if traffic will be increased I guess..

Should I store those table to `key-value store` and update it periodically?

Can you give me some idea to tackle this problem? How you usually handle this type of operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1 :**

As you suggested you can keep a local cache copy of in key-value pair on your local and updated the cache as regular interval.

**Solution 2 :**

You can use a MySql to Kafka Connector as below,
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/connectors/mysql.html
For every DML or table alter operations on your User Metadata Table there will be a respective event fired to a Kafka topic (e.g. db_events). You can run a thread in parallel in your Spark streaming job which polls db_events and updates your local cache key-value. 
This solution would make your application a near-real time application in true sense.
One over head I can see is that there will be need to run a Kafka Connect service with Mysql Connector (i.e. Debezium) as a plugin.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure whether load the whole table is the right choice, but once I calculated whole size of the user metadata, I realized it's very affordable! Also, Thanks a lot for letting me know `debezium`!